time synch problems
can someone decipher this error message for me please?
May 19 13:26:43 [servername] kernel: [1723623.817603] audit: type=1400 audit(1716139603.277:212): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="/usr/sbin/ntpd" name="/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf" pid=640240 comm="ntpd" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
What does this mean?
Im also seeing:
May 19 13:26:43 [servername] ntpd[640240]: kernel reports TIME_ERROR: 0x2041: Clock Unsynchronized
Are these 2 errors related?
